# changing colors of geom_col ggplot2 to show categorical variable at 3 sites

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart, yaxis

Long time fan of this site, first time user though.
Been searching for a similar/working result for this question.
I am trying to show the PROPORTION that each level of a 2 level factor appear at three locations. All in a side by side bar chart in ggplot.

Here is the code I've been using to (try) to create the chart. The result has been two charts: one using geom_bar and geom_col, respectively. What I'd like is essentially a combination of the two. The first, but with the colors and Y axis of the second.

Thank you!

```
    ggplot(df,aes(x = Stream,fill = death)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "dodge")+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(rep(c("gray45", "gray75"))))+
    labs(fill="Time of Death")
```

[image]

```
    death_stream <-df %>%
    group_by(Stream,Tree_Death)%>%
    summarise (n = n()) %>%
    mutate(rel.freq = paste0(round(100 * n/sum(n), 0), "%"))


    death_stream %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Stream,y = rel.freq)) + 
    geom_col(position = "dodge",fill = "grey50", colour = "black")+
    labs(fill="Time of Death")
```

[image]

Comment: What's the problem? You have the necessary code all there? Something like `ggplot(death_stream, aes(x = Stream, y = rel.freq, fill = Tree_Death)) + 
    geom_col(position = "dodge", colour = "black")+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray45", "gray75")) +
    labs(fill="Time of Death")`. Can't be sure without data.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Axeman, I figured it out.
the "class" of "rel.freq." was character. I tried specifying as numeric, but instead of

```
    <int>
```

it produced

```
   <dbl>
```

turns out all i had to do was revert the tibble BACK to data.frame and specify as numeric. Another way is to export as excel file and change the column "rel.freq" to NUMBERS in Excel.

```
    death_stream
    # A tibble: 6 x 4
    Stream Tree_Death     n percent
    <int>      <int> <int>   <int>
    1      1          0    25      33
    2      1          1    50      67
    3      2          0    17      30
    4      2          1    40      70
    5      3          0   120      70
    6      3          1    51      30
```